# Preventing nginx static content to be both on cookie-less subdomain and main domain

Tags: nginx, wordpress, static-content

UPDATE: Removing the rule below solves the unnecessary redirection. Now it just works fine. Though it is still reachable from two places, a canonical header solves the duplicate issue i guess.

I configured my site to have a static sub-domain like *static.example.com*. In this sub-domain's nginx config i have this:

```
if ($request_uri !~* "\.(jpe?g|gif|css|png|js|ico....)$") {
    rewrite ^(.*) https://www.example.com$1 permanent;
    break;
}
```

From W3 Total Cache panel i activated CDN to "Generic Mirror" and put the *static.example.com* as my CDN.

Now the images and css-js files in my site seems to come from the static subdomain. So far so good. But i can reach them from the *example.com* too. How can i prevent *example.com* to see the static content?

And also how can i disable access to the dynamic content from sub-domain?

Comment: Can you show a "curl -i" of the request? Rewrite sends a redirect to the client. You should also read this https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/

Comment: If i curl -i to the static.example.com/style.css the response is 301 Moved Permanently. If i make a request to the example.com/style.css the response is 200 OK.

Comment: That suggests to me that you've set things up incorrectly. The static subdomain is forwarding to the main domain and the main domain is serving the images. You need to post your full Nginx configuration if you want further help. I don't bother with cookieless domains personally, even though I like fast websites, partly because I use http/2. This article is somewhat interesting http://www.ravelrumba.com/blog/static-cookieless-domain/

Comment: You could also use CloudFlare free plan to serve your static content, brief article about that here https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169816-Can-I-serve-a-cookieless-domain-or-subdomain-through-CloudFlare-

Comment: Look to me like you're still redirecting from the subdomain to the main domain, against your stated objective. I'm surprised there's duplicate content, this rule should only apply to static content.

Comment: Nope, no redirection. Now images and other static files directly comes from the static sub domain.